# Permuted observations in Cox PH model in R

Tags: r, permutation, survival-analysis, cox

I have a data frame in the format required for `coxph` function in the survival package. The status of a subject can be either 0 (alive) or 1 (dead). I want to run a permutation on the status of subjects and re-run the analysis. In this case, one person who was alive for 10 time periods, might be assigned as dead for time period 6 now.

Should I specifically ask my code to ignore any observation after time period 6 for that person, or the `coxph` function itself does it automatically?

Comment: I don't know - I'd just try it and see. Do a simple example and see if there's any difference.

Answer (score 2):

As Gregor suggested, I simply created a small table of data and checked if coxph automatically ignores the observations after the first failure for each subject. It turned out that not really. You have to remove those observations manually if the nature of your failure indicates that there is no recovery from it.